# Print None if pd.read_html can't find any tables

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to print the table if it exists.

```
import pandas as pd

main_url='https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2000-2001/2000-2001-Premier-League-Stats'

squad_advanced_goalkeeping=pd.read_html(main_url,match='Squad Advanced Goalkeeping')[0] if pd.read_html(main_url,match='Squad Advanced Goalkeeping') else None
squad_advanced_goalkeeping
```

I thought this code was the solution but I still get "ValueError: No tables found matching pattern 'Squad Advanced Goalkeeping'"

Comment: If you dont pass the regex to read_html what do you get?

Comment: Note: When I view source on that page I do not see any text matching "Squad Advanced Goalkeeping" and apparently neither does pandas.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python exception handling using `try-except` blocks

```
import pandas as pd

main_url='https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2000-2001/2000-2001-Premier-League-Stats'

try:
    squad_advanced_goalkeeping = pd.read_html(main_url,match='Squad Advanced Goalkeeping')[0] 
except ValueError as e:
    squad_advanced_goalkeeping = None

print(squad_advanced_goalkeeping)
```